# I need help designing walls for a game I am working on

Tags: modeling, texturing

I have been modelling for a fangame recently and I needed help with making the walls. I want the walls to look like the ones from FNAF 1, but I do not know how to model them. I have tried using an image texture, but it only gets half of the wall onto the plane for some reason. Can someone help me make a texture for them please?

P.S. What the walls look like
[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. If your previous question was put on hold, address raised the issues by editing it so it can be reopened rather than post a new one, otherwise see [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: Hello, you say that you've tried with an Image Texture and you've failed, maybe pack the image (File > External Data > Pack Resources) and share your file? Use a platform like workupload for example

Comment: Do you want me to use workupload to send the blend file? Or do you want me to put a picture of what the image texture is doing?